# slide show function after ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, slide

My home page has following slider

```
function slider() {
    $('.slideshow li:gt(0)').hide();
    setInterval(function(){
        $('.slideshow li:first-child').fadeOut(2000).next('li').fadeIn(2000).end().appendTo('.slideshow');
        }, 4000);

}
```

Navigation bar loads page via ajax load method.

```
$("#menu li").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = $("a", this).attr("href");
    $(".info_box").slideUp("slow", function(){
        $(".info_box").load(url, function(){
            $(".info_box").slideDown("slow");
            if(url == "index.php") {
              slider();
            }
        }); 
    });
```

function slider works fine on very first visit, but after ajax load when i go back to slider page (index.php) it doesn't work so i recall the function which solved the problem but slider doesn't work smoothly its sliding images very fast after ajax call.

Comment: Instead of load why don't you use .ajax() method.. Then You can call the slider() function in the complete function of the ajax request.. ??

Comment: Its also creating same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Two setIntervals are probably running at the same time. You should put the function on want to run inside of a $(document).ready